# Sorting with SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I want to sort with the WHERE function of a Query. 
The only problem now is that I want the products to show all at first, and when you click sort that it sorts on page.

### The Sort Query

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artikels WHERE   
        soort='".mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['soort'])."'");
```

### The Show all Query

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artikels WHERE soort='dahua' ");
```

Somehow I need to combine these 2 But When I Do this it stops working, and doesnt even sort. When I seperate the Sort or Show all Query it does work.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artikels WHERE 
       soort-'dahua' AND soort='".mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['soort'])."'");
```

I'd love it if someone helps me out with this because I'm now stuck on my project.

Many Thanks,

~Dave

Comment: Please learn to use parametrized queries.  As you have written it now, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection in your queries.  See http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for examples of how to do queries the right way in PHP.

Comment: I'm still a learning student in PHP, and I will read the page. But this Comment doesn't yet provide the solution for my problem.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: do you really want to sort, not filter?

Comment: +1 for the comment about using PDO (Told by someone who is switching  from mysql to postgresql). Apart from that, I do not understand what do you pretend in particular. Why using ORDER BY is not suitable for your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter records from a table use `WHERE` e.g.

```
WHERE soort='dahua'
```

to filter records with multiple matches use `OR` eg.

```
WHERE soort='dahua' OR soort='somethingelse'
```

You sort the results using `ORDER BY` e.g.

```
ORDER BY soort
```

You can add `DESC` or `ASC` for direction

Answer (score 0):

My first guess, without knowing what "doesn't work" means (syntax error?  Incorrect results?), is that you have `soort-'dahua'` instead of `soort='dahua'`

Comment: Oh sorry mistyped it while posting haha :) 
The problem is that It doesnt filter when I combine Those 2 Options.

Comment: @DavePiersma: That's why you don't retype your query, but cut & paste it.  Who knows what other changes you made from your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

This question is hard to answer, mainly because `WHERE` filters and doesn't sort, but I think you may wanted to perform an `OR`:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * 
    FROM artikels 
    WHERE soort='dahua' OR soort='%s'", 
        mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['soort'])
);
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Sorry I ment Filter indeed.

Comment: It still does Filter, but doesnt show all the results at first.

Comment: **UPDATE**

It does show all products now but it doesnt filter them.

Comment: @DavePiersma That's kind of the point isn't it? If all are shown, nothing is filtered. I'm not exactly sure what you want at this point. Sorting or filtering?

Comment: I want it to show all products and when for example I click on a button what says show only : dahua or dahua2 or dahua3 ect..

Answer (score 0):

You can sort rows by using the [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) clause. Here's a contrived example

`SELECT name, age FROM users ORDER BY name DESC;`